# Filling the enclosed areas with random colors - Haskell - Friday

Tags: image, haskell, image-processing

I am trying to perform not very complex image analysis to try and find distinct shapes and calculate some of their parameters like area and perimeter (in pixels) and I am trying to do this in Haskell (I wanted to do that to try and work with functional programming language).

The first task in line is to count the amount of spoons on the image:
[image: Image of 6 spoons]
I am using [Friday](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/friday-0.2.2.0) Haskell package to work with images.

My idea was to use the Friday's edge detection and then fill all of the enclosed areas with it's fill function. The first one would require me to iterate over image's pixels until i've stumbled upon a black pixel. Than I would fill the area and continue the search in the image (which now has one of it's objects filled). I could color different objects with random colors and associate these colors with their objects to find their areas and perimeters.

Here is how this image looks after I've applied edge detection to it:
[image]

I was unable to find the way of iterating over all of the pixels though.
I've found those **read** and **readLinear** functions in the following package: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/friday-0.2.2.0/docs/Vision-Image-Mutable.html#v:linearRead, but I am not sure how to use them and I was unable to deduce that from their type signature since I am very very new to Haskell.

Here is the code that does all of the image reading, grayscaling and edge detecting:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Prelude hiding (filter)
import System.Environment (getArgs)

import Vision.Detector.Edge (canny)
import Vision.Image
import Vision.Image.Storage.DevIL (Autodetect (..), load, save)

detectEdges :: RGBA -> Grey
detectEdges img =
  let grey = convert img :: Grey
      -- Img blurring --
      blurRadius = 2
      blurred = gaussianBlur blurRadius (Nothing :: Maybe Double) grey :: Grey

      -- Sobel applying --
      sobelRadius = 2
      lowThreshold = 256
      highThreshold = 1024
  in (canny sobelRadius lowThreshold highThreshold blurred) :: Grey

processImg :: RGBA -> RGBA
processImg img =
  let edges = detectEdges img
  -- Here goes all of the important stuff
  in convert edges :: RGBA

main :: IO ()
main = do
  [input, output] <- getArgs

  io <- load Autodetect input
  case io of
    Left err             -> do
      putStrLn "Unable to load the image:"
      print err

    Right (img :: RGBA)  -> do
      mErr <- save Autodetect output (processImg img)
      case mErr of
        Nothing  ->
          putStrLn "Success."
        Just err -> do
          putStrLn "Unable to save the image:"
          print err
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: will you always have this background or should this work with arbitrary images?
Unfortunately I have no idea of Haskell

Comment: Thats unfortunate since the question is more about Haskell than anything else.

Comment: Could you present your current code that reads, grays scales, and edge detects?  As with your last question, I'd like to answer but am far too lazy to re-produce the initial steps.

Comment: I've added the initial steps as you were asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I find area and perimeter of connected components?

You can use the contour tracing from `Vision.Image.Contour` to get all contour perimeters.  First lets start with getting the edges like you have:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Prelude as P
import System.Environment (getArgs)

import Vision.Detector.Edge (canny)
import Vision.Image
import Vision.Primitive.Shape
import Vision.Image.Storage.DevIL (Autodetect (..), load, save)
import Vision.Image.Transform(floodFill)
import Control.Monad.ST (runST, ST)
import Vision.Image.Contour

-- Detects the edge of the image with the Canny's edge detector.
--
-- usage: ./canny input.png output.png
main :: IO ()
main = do
    [input, output] <- getArgs

    -- Loads the image. Automatically infers the format.
    io <- load Autodetect input

    case io of
        Left err             -> do
            putStrLn "Unable to load the image:"
            print err
        Right (grey :: Grey) -> do
            let blurred, edges :: Grey
                edges = canny 2 256 1024 blurred :: Grey
```

Here's where we acquire contours.  Due to a bug in the draw function, which I use later, I'll blur first to get contours with distinct inner and outer points. This will get patched eventually...

```
                cs           = contours (blur 2 edges :: Grey)
                goodContours = P.filter goodSize (allContourIds cs)
```

Now we have a value of this `Contours` type which includes a valid `ContourId` for each connected component.  For each `ContourId` you can get its area with `contourSize` and perimeter with `contourPerimeter`.  The size of the perimeter is just the length of the list of perimeter points.

I just did a really overly-tailored filter, called `goodSize` to get the spoons, but you can play with area and perimeter all you'd like:

```
                goodSize x   = let ((xmin,xmax),(ymin,ymax)) = contourBox cs x
                               in xmax-xmin > 60 && xmax-xmin < 500 &&
                                  ymax-ymin > 100 && ymax-ymin < 500

                final, filledContours :: RGBA
                filledContours =
                   convert $ drawContours cs (shape edges) Fill goodContours
```

Optionally, for each contour use floodFill to get a color.  Here I just use three colors and fill whichever contours are first in the list.  The contours list is ordered top-to-bottom left-to-right so this will look odd-ish.  You could `sortBy xmin goodContours` to get a left-right ordering.

```
                floodStart = concatMap (take 1 . contourPerimeter cs) goodContours
                colors = cycle [RGBAPixel 255 0 0 255, RGBAPixel 0 255 0 255, RGBAPixel 0 0 255 255]
                final = runST doFill
```

The fill operation is using the `ST` monad, which you can find many questions about here on StackOverflow.

```
                doFill :: forall s. ST s RGBA
                doFill = do
                          m <- thaw filledContours :: ST s (MutableManifest RGBAPixel s)
                          mapM_ (\(p,c) -> floodFill p c m) (zip floodStart colors)
                          return =<< unsafeFreeze m

            -- Saves the edges image. Automatically infers the output format.
            mErr <- save Autodetect output final
            case mErr of
                Nothing  ->
                    putStrLn "Success."
                Just err -> do
                    putStrLn "Unable to save the image:"
                    print err

contourBox cs x =
  let ps = contourPerimeter cs x
      (xs,ys) = unzip $ P.map (\(Z :. x :. y) -> (x,y)) ps
  in ((minimum xs, maximum xs), (minimum ys, maximum ys))
```

The end result is:

[image: RGB Spoons]

Comment: Wow thank you for going through all of that hastle to implement the solution. I was working on it myself, but didn't quite finish it yet, so I didn't close the question before I was done in case I got more questions.

Comment: Where can I find any docs on this 'contour' function? I've scanned through your friday's fork on github but didn't find anything.

Comment: I now have access to the main repo: https://github.com/RaphaelJ/friday/blob/master/src/Vision/Image/Contour.hs

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see a question in your posting, the closest seems to be:

> I was unable to find the way of iterating over all of the pixels though.

You can itereate over all the pixels using `map` but then... that's just a map and you'll get no state (it's not a fold after all).  So you might want to make your own primitive recursive function and just index each pixel using [`index`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/friday-0.2.2.0/docs/Vision-Image-Class.html#v:index) which is the same as [`!`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/friday-0.2.2.0/docs/Vision-Image-Class.html#v:-33-).

You also said:

> My idea was to use the Friday's edge detection and then fill all of the enclosed areas with it's fill function.

Well if you fill "all of the enlosed areas" then your whole picture will be <strike>white</strike> filled with whatever the outer outline is depending on fill strategy - notice the larger rectangle encompassing your whole image.  I suggest you do a contour trace and filter on some simple things like perimeter size, height, width, or ratios.  My contour modules isn't pushed up to hackage yet but you can get it from github. Notice the `drawContour` function should work for you once its properly functioning (part of why I won't push it up to Hackage just yet).